# Does every semantic ambiguity produce an equivalent syntactic ambiguity?

Tags: syntax, semantics

I was reading this question [Syntactic and semantic ambiguity](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28636/syntactic-and-semantic-ambiguity?rq=1#), and there is a comment from @jlawler on how the sentence "He's mad" have different syntactic affordances:

Original comment:

> "He's mad" can mean "He's angry" or "He's crazy", but the syntax is the same.

Jlawler's reply:

> Though the two senses have different syntactic affordances. Mad in the 'crazy' sense is polar and therefore can be modified by absolutely, whereas in the 'angry' sense it's non-polar and therefore can't, so that He's absolutely mad is unambiguous. It's not that easy to separate syntax and semantics; words of a feather flock together.

Is it true that for all polysemes/lexical ambiguities there are different syntactic affordances it could take? So that you can add a word like "very" or "absolutely" to resolve the ambiguity?

I don't really understand how it would work for homonyms that doesn't change their parts of speech. For example:

> "This is a bar."

Here bar can have both the meaning as in a steel bar and a bar where people go to drink. In this case, both senses of the word being a noun - wouldn't they take the same syntactic affordances?

I understand how in the "He's mad" case, the two words are adjectives and turns out to have different syntactic affordances, but I guess that was just a special case where we could discern the different meaning with a test like adding "absolutely". But is that the case with every homonym in the language?

There's also this other sentence that's mentioned in one of the answers to the question.

> "You're finished"
> https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/28641/31833

Comment: Pretty sure you could add an adjective or an adverb which would only apply to one of the meanings to resolve any such ambiguity, such as 'This is a long bar.'